# Calling kexec_load from kernel code to reload the same kernel itself once

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, boot

[`kexec_load`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kexec_load.2.html) is used to load another kernel from the current running kernel without reboot.

So my question is: How can I use it to load the current kernel again, from the current running kernel (aka it reloads itself), by calling `kexec_load` in the kernel code? I know `kexec_load` can be changed to a function that can be called from internal kernel, not just userspace. Also, I don't want to load the kernel file again, if possible.

I will have conditional code to make it reloads just *once*, so you don't need to worry about it will reload forever.

Comment: kexec_load copies from user space. kexec_load_file will copy from a file in block cache.

Comment: And how do you think it will get  the data it needs to execute? TL;DR: what you are asking is impossible. Try again. (Of course many thing are possible, and this one, but you need either to reserve and preserve images of what kexec is using, or alter the Linux decompressor code to do that for you)